# How to fill pointer array from text file?

Tags: c++, text-files

I'm working on a school project that is due today, and I'm stuck on a probably simple problem.

I need to make the game "Hangman" and the task I'm stuck on is to fill an array of pointers from text file (I need to read the pictures for wrong answers).

```
void ReadScenes(string *scenes[10])
 {
ifstream inFile("Scenes.txt");
if (inFile.is_open())
{
    int i = 0;
    string scene;
    while ((inFile >> scene)&&(i<10))
    {
        *scenes[i] = scene;
            i++;        
    }
}
}
int main()
{
  char *scenes[10];
  ReadScenes(scenes);
}
```

And my text file looks like this:

```
char *scene1 =
    "                      \n"
    "                      \n"
    "                      \n"
    "                      \n"
    "                      \n"
    "                      \n"
    "       *              \n"
    "      * *             \n"
    "     *   *            \n";


char *scene2 =
    "       *              \n"
    "       *              \n"
    "       *              \n"
    "       *              \n"
    "       *              \n"
    "       *              \n"
    "       *              \n"
    "      * *             \n"
    "     *   *            \n";
```

And so on.

The code in method was working for reading passwords because they were separated with spaces. So I have 10 scenes and I want to save them in array.

Comment: *I'm stuck on is to fill an array of pointers* - then don't use an array of pointers?

Comment: `ReadScenes` takes a `std::string**` but you give it `char**`. Won't work.

Comment: why is it an array of pointers? You can fill an array with pointers, but if those pointers dont point anywhere thats rather pointless. You also need to store the strings themself somewhere. In general if you need to store some instances in a container, and you use a container of pointers, then you still need to store the instances somewhere. Simply use an array of object instead of an array of pointers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One problem is that you think that the files you read should be C++-like files with variable declarations. That's not how it works.

You should put the contents of the file into a normal C++ source file and build with it.

Something like

```
std::string scenes[] = {
    // Scene 1
    "                      \n"
    "                      \n"
    "                      \n"
    "                      \n"
    "                      \n"
    "                      \n"
    "       *              \n"
    "      * *             \n"
    "     *   *            \n",

    // Scene 2
    "       *              \n"
    "       *              \n"
    "       *              \n"
    "       *              \n"
    "       *              \n"
    "       *              \n"
    "       *              \n"
    "      * *             \n"
    "     *   *            \n",

    // And so on...
};
```

If you use an IDE add the source file to your project.

If you use e.g. `g++` to build on the command-line then

```
g++ -Wall main.cpp scenes.cpp -o my_program
```

<sub>Where `scenes.cpp` is the source file containing the `scenes` array.</sub>

---

If you need to use external *text* files, without any C++ code, then it's actually very easy: Just store the text, as is, without quotes or anything resembling C++ declarations or statements.

Since you know that each "scene" is exactly nine lines (and perhaps an extra line to separate two scenes) you use a `for` loop to read the line.

So your text file could then look like

```
           *              
          * *             
         *   *            

           *              
           *              
           *              
           *              
           *              
           *              
           *              
          * *             
         *   *
```

Then to load it

```
constexpr size_t NUMBER_OF_SCENES = 2;  // With the example scene file in this answer
constexpr size_t LINES_PER_SCENE = 9;

std::ifstream scene_file("scenes.txt");

std::array<std::string, NUMBER_OF_SCENES> scenes;

// Loop to read all scenes
for (std::string& scene : scenes)
{
    std::string line;

    // Loop to read all lines for a single scene
    for (unsigned line_number = 0; line_number < LINES_PER_SCENE && std::getline(scene_file, line); ++line_number)
    {
        // Add line to the current scene
        scene += line + '\n';
    }

    // Read the empty line between scenes
    // Don't care about errors here
    std::getline(scene_file, line);
}
```

Comment: It is possible that I do it without pointers(but i still don't know how to). But I can not save scenes in .cpp file, they must be in .txt file because the teacher require us to do so.

Comment: @Jure Then you need to rethink the format of the file. You can not have C++ declarations or C++ string literals in them (unless you want to develop a C++ declaration parser, which is probably a little out of scope of your assignment). Updated answer with example file and code

Answer (score 1):

If you got stuck, it's mostly because you overcomplicated the solution. There's no need to use an array of pointers.

Instead, simply store your screen as an array of strings, and use `std::getline` to read them from file:

```
std::array<std::string, 3> read_file(std::istream& s) {
    std::array<std::string, 3> result;
    for (auto & row : result)
        std::getline(s, row);
    return result;
}
```

You've also called your variable definitions "files"; it's not the same. Typically files reside on a disk. The solution above is flexible enough (thanks to `std::istream` interface) to accept either a memory-based `std::stringstream`, like in my example, or e.g. `std::ifstream("your_path.txt")`.

If you originally intended to store everything in source code, simply storing everything in the form it needs to be used sounds like a better option.

[Working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e882c71e830a08a).